# View.onClickListener() not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I've been trying Android Studio and I've struggled at the beginning. I want to create a button that pops a Toast message on a click. I wrote a simple code, but the program starts and then Android shuts it down. I don't really understand, because this code works perfectly in Eclipse, it's really easy. Is it just an Android Studio problem or am I so bad? Imports are ok. When I run a plain new project, it runs. It crashes only with the new onClick button.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

   Button button;
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            writeIt();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I see, there's a guy with the same problem: [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711457/android-studio-0-3-1-button-setonclicklistenerthis-crashes-the-app?rq=1)

Comment: and what does the DDMS log say?

Comment: Does it crash when you click on the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add a Button view to the activity_main.xml file? By default it seems that Android Studio populates it with a fragment only. If that's the case, your call to setOnClickListener will throw a NullPointerException.